# ASP.Net MVC 4 empty property in Create action overwrites default SQL value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Model `League`, and the corresponsing SQL Server table has a `DateCreated` column that uses a default SQL value of `getdate()`.

When I add a new `League`, the `DateCreated` column gets written with a `null` value, which I'm guessing is a result of the EF overwriting the SQL `getdate()` function. Is there a way to get the EF to ignore this column when adding a new row? Here's my create action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(LeagueCreateViewModel lcv)
    {
        League league = new League();
        league.Title = lcv.Title;
        league.SiteId = lcv.SiteId;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Leagues.Add(league);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.SiteId = new SelectList(db.Sites, "Id", "Title", league.SiteId);
        return View(lcv);
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you change the DateCreatedColumn so it won't allow null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EF 4.1 then it's not supported and you have to be explicit about it - take care of that in code. What you an do is create a partial class for your object and do the "defaulting" in your object's constructor.

```
public partial class League {
    public League() {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now; 
        // or DateTime.UtcNow, depends on your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: OK thanks, I'll give that a try. One more thing - in the [HttpPost] Edit action, I won't want this property set or updated at all, so what would I do in that situation?

Comment: In EF 4.1, if you don't set that value that won't get updated.